# Google Cloud Functions with Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am planning to deploy a small project on Google Cloud Functions and is using the Google Cloud Storage as well.

I notice that instead of using the `os module` to call the credential, I need to call from the service account file.

**e.g.**

```py
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('xx.json') 
 storage_client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials)
```

**Then, the error**I　dont' have much experence to tell which point shall I check.

[image]

I have do the `from google.oauth2 import service_account` and `from google.cloud import storage` and put the credential json key under the cloud functions' temp.

I wonder which process or details have I missed?

Do I need to manually activate the Oauth permision on somewhere or something?
Any pointers? Welcome for any advices and comments.

Comment: If you deploy your code on Cloud FUnction, you don't need a service account key file. In general, you should never need it. Use ADC instead

Comment: The log that you have shared is the [audit log](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit). If you want to see what error is happening, look at the [cloud functions log](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/logs?service=cloudfunctions.googleapis.com).